# Converting an entire react component to a fully functional HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to convert a react component to a html file. I tried it to do by getting the document.body.innerHTML content in to a HTML file. But the case is only the inline css and the HTML content is exported. The event handlers that attached to those HTML elements are not there. The events are not binded in the HTML element as well. In other words the JavaScript part is not exported at all. Is there a way or a library to do that ? or is it impossible to convert an react component to a html that works exactly as the react component ?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: In my knowledge, there is not any library to do it. You need to do it manually. You have to rewrite react functions in javascript.

Comment: Building a React app creates a *.js and a *.css file. Those are linked in a mostly empty index.html file. So you could write an app that uses only that component, then build it, and the result is pretty much what you want, provided you insert the script and stylesheet in the HTML doc.

Comment: Isn't this what building the app and having babel transpile the JSX into plain JS/CSS/html basically does?

Comment: Acually I have written a basic react app to create chair arrangements in a hall. The case is the fully functional html and js code of the created chair arrangement should be saved in a separate html file to serve it in a php application. I know this question is littlebit weird. I was able to extract only the html and inline css up to now.